# How to find interpolated values in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

Consider a list as

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5};
```

If I apply interpolation on it,

```
f = ListInterpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}];
```

**Edit 1:** Now I wish to add two values in between any two consecutive elements such that the new list becomes

```
  list1 = {1, N@f[4/3], N@f[5/3], 2, N@f[7/3], N@f[8/3], 3, N@f[10/3], 
  N@f[11/3], 5, N@f[13/3], N@f[14/3], 8, N@f[14/3], N@f[13/3], 5}
```

I tried the following:

```
f1 = DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[Table[
    Table[InverseFunction[f][i], {i, list[[j]], list[[j + 1]], 
      0.33}], {j, 1, Length@list - 1}]]]
```

However, it's not giving me the desired output.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you mean with _I wish to add two values in between any two consecutive elements_?

Comment: `list2 = f /@ Range[1, Length[list], 1/3] /. x_Rational :> N[x]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.